# Proper use of <slow_backend> for local.xml implementation

Tags: redis, slowbackend

I've scoured the web and this SE section, what I find is either not clear or completely outdated.

I keep coming across articles about a 2 level caching system, a `fast backend` and a `slow backend`.

Looking at the **local.xml.additional** file, there is nothing about a slow backend option, yet I keep reading about it.

So my question is there any benefit to implementing this?

Is it done as follows:

```
<backend>Cm_Cache_Backend_Redis</backend>
         <slow_backend>database</slow_backend>
        <slow_backend_store_data>0</slow_backend_store_data> 
        <backend_options>
            <server>127.0.0.1</server> <!-- or absolute path to unix socket for better performance -->
            <port>6379</port>
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best guide that I could find is: https://www.nbs-system.co.uk/blog-2/magento-optimization-howto-en.html

From Fabrizio:

> Two-level caching is widely used in computing. Basically it is about having a small, but fast cache that is used for the first lookup, and if the data cannot be found in the first level it will be looked up in another cache that's usually bigger (mostly unlimited in size), but slower. This gives you both advantages: speed and size. Cache implementations usually have different features like tagging

http://fbrnc.net/blog/2011/10/magento-zend-frameworks-twolevels-cache-backend-mess

Depending on what infrastructure you have in place you could implement Redis + Database as fast and slow.